# Cannot subscript a value of type anyobject

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I've currently upgraded to the new Xcode 7, and the following code never had any errors with swift 1.2, but now its telling me that :

> Cannot subscript a value of type any object

```
var imageArray : NSArray = []
let url = NSURL(string: (self.imageArray[indexPath.row][0] as? String)!)
```

I know its about `[0]` but how do i rewrite it to be accepted ?

Comment: What is contained inside `imageArray`? Can you show the code where you create `imageArray`.

Comment: I've updated the question @Fogmeister

Comment: So `imageArray` is an Objective-C `NSArray` but what is actually inside it? What do you put into it?

Comment: its a multidimensional array, first array has nothing, second one has urls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so first you are using an `NSArray`. You can drop that and make everything much easier.

In Swift always use strong typing where possible. Avoid Any and AnyObject when they are not needed. (They are VERY RARELY needed).

The error is happening because you're not telling the code what is actually in the `imageArray`.

Also, `imageArray` tells me the array is full of images. Name your variables more descriptively. `imageUrlStringArray` or `arrayOfImageUrlArrays`. Something more descriptive anyway.

Declare `imageArray` like...

```
var imageArray = [[String]]()
```

This tells the compiler that `imageArray` is a 2D array with `Strings` at the second level.

Now you can create your URL easily...

```
guard 
    let urlString = imageArray[indexPath.row].first,
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    else { // Handle the inability to create a URL }

// Do something with the url
```

Comment: i will check it in a bit :)

Comment: Im getting the following error on : guard let ... initializer for conditioal binding must have optional type not String .

Comment: @AaoIi edited. It may need altering slightly. I am writing on Safari with no documentation. You are writing in Xcode with access to docs. This should give you the general idea.